# failing to replace text according to a predefined list

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, replaceall

I'm trying to make a function which replaces specific strings within a set of code according to a pre defined list of search words and what it should be replaced with,

```
render = (data,list) => {
let temp = data;
  for(let i in list){
    temp.split(i).join(list[i]);
   //temp.replace(new RegExp(i, 'g'), list[i]); even this doesn't work
  }
return temp;
}
let test = render("<h1>a1</h1>",
 { "a1" : "Hello World" });
```

I don't see any errors, it just doesn't replace anything and returns the original data as it is, if I use the code used for the replacement separately and manually place in the values in the regExp or split join functions, it works fine..

//edit

The Expected input and output should be,

```
let temp = "<h1> $1 </h1>";
console.log( render(test, { "$1":"Hello World" } ) );
```

This is supposed to output,

```
<h1> Hello World </h1>
```

but I instead get

```
<h1> $1 </h1>
```

as it is.

Comment: replace or join does not modify original string

Comment: what is the correct way of modifying the string which is got through the argument? could you please elaborate..

Comment: save the result of `replace`, and return the result. Please check @Vivek 's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's solution -

```js
render = (data, list) => {
  let temp = data;
  for (let i in list) {
    temp = temp.replace(new RegExp(i, 'g'), list[i]);
  }
  return temp;
}
let test = render("<h1>a1</h1>", {
  "a1": "Hello World"
});

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, could you please explain what was the cause of it not working?

Comment: @AdarshHegde `replace` method is not replacing in-place of string, you have to re-assign it back to `temp` - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)